# Problem while converting nsstring to nsdate and viceversa

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am facing a problem while converting from date to string and string to date.

code is :

```
NSDate *date=[NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];
NSString *dateString=[formatter stringFromDate:date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];
NSDate *date2 = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
```

while printing it is  displaying the different date.
Kindly help me

Comment: Could you post the output dates that are being displayed please? Thanks.

Comment: datestring is :27/05/2011

date2 is :2011-05-26 18:30:00 +0000.I need only 27/05/2011 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDate always returns in GMT. So `date2` is right. Its in GMT. You can consider it as `27/05/2011 00:00:00 +0530 IST`. There is nothing wrong with this.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/YYYY"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"IST"]];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormat stringFromDate:date2]);
```

Doing this should return in IST.

You can also get `date2` like this,

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSInteger flag = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:flag fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDate *date2 = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
```